# How do I select rows, order by date desc in Google Sheets?

Tags: mysql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have column A as ID , column B as Score and column C as Date in Google Sheet and I wanted to select the data and ORDER by column C DESC.

The result come out as below:

```
A   B   C
123 100 30/07/19
111 100 30/07/19
113 100 29/07/19
112 100 28/07/19
115 100 02/08/19
016 100 01/08/19
```

The result should be:

```
115 100 02/08/19
016 100 01/08/19
123 100 30/07/19
111 100 30/07/19
113 100 29/07/19
112 100 28/07/19
```

How can I solve this with SQL in Google Sheet?

```
Select A,B,C Where B LIKE '% 100 &%' Order By C DESC
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SQL, but can you explain the order you expect column C to come in? I see it's not by date.

Comment: Do you use Mysql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a formatting issue... format column A as Plain Text, column B as Number and column C as Date. then use this formula:

```
=QUERY(A2:C, "select A,B,C where B = 100 order by C desc", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Adding the final Zero argument into the query to disable headers solved this for me!
=QUERY(range, query, header_rows). Even with correct formatting, ordering was being weird because it thought the first row was a header.